# Should I make the call for chrome.storage.sync.set asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I'm building an extension that uses the chrome.storage.sync API. I know that I have to use async code for chrome.storage.sync.get because of *reasons (i don't fully understand either)* by using async/await. Should I make the function that calls chrome.storage.sync.set asynchronous too? Should all chrome extension API calls be async?

Little more info: I'm using react so maybe it has something to do with the component life cycle or the event loop? I have no idea I'm very new.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: there's no need to mark the Chrome storage callback async unless you want to use `await`. You also don't need to mark a function that calls the Chrome storage API as async.

Examples:

```
// works just fine without async
chrome.storage.sync.get('someKey', function(obj) {
   console.log(obj)
})

// async allows you to use await in the callback function with Promises
chrome.storage.sync.get('someKey', async function(obj) {
   var response = await fetch('...');
})

// no need to make the outer `setData` function async
function setData() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({someKey: 123, function() {
    // ...
  })
}
```

Marking a function as `async` is basically just to use the `await` keyword within it. `await` is handy because it solves "callback hell", where you have many functions that require callbacks and you have to chain them together.

Additionally, one day (see [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328932)) Chrome's extensions API will return Promises instead of requiring callbacks as they do today, so writing Chrome extension code will use async functions a lot more. Firefox already uses Promises in their extension API, but for backward-compatibility reasons also supports using callbacks.

Comment: the thing is whenever I tried to call the function that calls chrome.storage.sync.get in my react component it always returned undefined, so I had to do the async await so I actually got a result

Comment: It would be super helpful to see a minimal example so we can see what's going on. But yeah, if that function you're calling is returning a Promise, then if you don't use either await or promise.then(callback) it probably won't work correctly.